# Ubuntu in silent mode

Tags: ubuntu, installation, silent-install

I have made a custom distribution of Ubuntu. I totally changed the installation process (the user feedback mostly) but what I want is always start in silent mode. I mean, the default installation mode has to be silent mode installation.

Which files are in charge of that? or what do I have to change in Ubuntu installation files in order of do that.

Answer (score 2):

Such an installation is called an unattended installation. You could use [preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/appendix-preseed.html) for answering installation questions and setting custom configurations.

From the [introduction](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/preseed-intro.html):

> Preseeding provides a way to set answers to questions asked during the installation process, without having to manually enter the answers while the installation is running. This makes it possible to fully automate most types of installation and even offers some features not available during normal installations.

Beware of a limitation:

> Although most questions used by debian-installer can be preseeded using this method, there are some notable exceptions. You must (re)partition an entire disk or use available free space on a disk; it is not possible to use existing partitions.

Comment: Yes thanks! I'm using preseeding now. Sorry i didn't mention. My bad. What i'm trying to do is to configure the installation to show none text message at all (Cause I have some language requirements to fulfill), I mean, just a progress bar or simulate silent mode at least. Is that possible right?

Comment: I don't know if that's possible. I've asked it on Askubuntu: [How to show just a progress bar during a preseeded installation?](http://askubuntu.com/q/48353/6969)

Comment: Thank u very much! I'm following. If I get into it I'll post it here

Comment: If you've such specific Ubuntu questions, you'd better ask those on http://askubuntu.com/